# The effect of living backwards

Tags: visual

Can you find the seven differences in the reflected (right-side) picture?

[image]
Engraving credit: [John Tenniel](https://www.google.com/search?q=alice%20tweedle%20dee%20tweedle%20dum%20public%20domain%20art&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fm&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRppX-jZ3aAhXH2VMKHRU-DSAQpwUIIA&biw=907&bih=449&dpr=1.5)
**CLICK TO ENLARGE**

> "That's the effect of living backwards," the Queen said kindly: "it always makes one a little giddy at first--"

Comment: I have to ask - Is this your original drawing?

Comment: And I also have to ask...4 answers in the span of 20 seconds? This is amazing :O

Comment: @Rubio It's a Tenniel illustration from Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-Glass*.

Comment: And obviously the Literature guy responds :D

Comment: 100 bonus imaginary points to @Randal'Thor for recognizing Tenniel's work. 200 bonus imaginary points to Rubio for thinking I'm an excellent artist. BTW: The "thing" over Tweedle Dum's hat is Tenniel's classic signature.

Comment: @Chowzen It would be wise to credit the artist explicitly and to indicate under what license, law, etc. you're allowed to copy it here. (I assume it's public domain, but it never hurts to note it.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, it's by John Tenniel, who was illustrating Lewis Carrol's book, *Alice Through the Looking Glass and What she found there,* and it is [public domain.](https://www.google.com/search?q=alice+tweedle+dee+tweedle+dum+public+domain+art&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fm&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRppX-jZ3aAhXH2VMKHRU-DSAQpwUIIA&biw=907&bih=449&dpr=1.5)

Comment: I meant in the question itself. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Full Answer:

1.

> The right one on the left picture has no buttons.

2.

> Her socks lose their stripes on the right hand side.

3.

> The right guy on the right is NOT looking (with his eyes) on the polar opposite of what he was like on the left side.

4.

> There is an extra dot on her arm.

5.

> The claws in the middle are different.

6.

> Alice's shadow is different in both pictures.

7.

> One of the thing's hats has a different thing on top.

Comment: Yay! All 7 now :-D +1

Comment: @Randal'Thor Lol This is actually most of us though...posts a partial answer and then whenever you find one edit your post until you get all 7 XD

Answer (score 12):

Differences circled:

Hover to spoil them.

(click to enlarge)

**Warning:** lots of freehand

> [image]

Written Differences: (R-L on R image)

> 1. Stripes on the girls socks
>  2. Her Elbow doesn't have that little shading
>  3. The buttons are missing on the guy on the right (I had initially counted each of his buttons as their *own* difference)
>  4. Signature thingy on top of his head (guy on the right)
>  5. Rock? Shading? under the umbrella handle (yes at first it looks like an axe/pick, but if you look closely you'll see that it's an umbrella)
>  6+7. are the other 2 buttons (see #3)
>  
>  **The *actual* other 2, which I noticed after @NL628 posted [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63211/45083)**:
>  6. Guy on right is looking in the other direction
>  Girls shadow is different (lighter)

Comment: Sniped omg wow :O

Comment: Nice first answer! :-D

Comment: +1 for [free hand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/216712). Why not add a list explaining the differences, though?

Comment: @jpmc26 I was planning on, thank you for the reminder. It's been updated.

Answer (score 9):

> [image] 
>  Missing buttons on Dum
>  
>  Shadow of umbrella 
>  Thing above Dum's hat
>  Mark on elbow of Alice
>  Dum is looking the opposite direction
>  Alice's Shadow is different
>  Stripes on Alice's leg

Answer (score 7):

1. > Missing buttons on Tweedledum's belly.
2. > Some odd symbol on the tree just above Tweedledum's head.
3. > The umbrella handle's shadow has disappeared.
4. > No stripes on Alice's foreground leg.
5. > Tweedledum is looking at Tweedledee instead of at Alice.
6. > Missing spot on Alice's elbow.
7. > Alice lost her shadow.

Comment: Yay! All 7 now :D +1

Answer (score 3):

All in all, there are 6 parts altered in either half of the image:

> [image]

Comment: OP says seven; you must have missed one :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Though I must say, the fact that he didn't read that the "OP said 7" meant that he has lots of determination. I would have only found like 2 or 3 if the OP didn't tell me anything.

Comment: @NL628 When I started searching for the differences, there weren't any answers submitted, so I hurried :) Seems like there are always some faster people on here.