# Neither more, nor less

Tags: visual

Can you find the... um...er... I forgot how many! But there are *some* differences in the reflected (right-side) picture, that's for sure.

Who's the FGITW *now?*

[image]
(engraving credit: [John Tenniel](https://www.google.com/search?biw=907&bih=449&tbs=sur%3Afm&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Z2rDWqDCI4Ht_QbSyoGYAQ&q=tenniel%20sheep&oq=tenniel%20sheep&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10170.10170.0.10565.1.1.0.0.0.0.149.149.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.qqmLQqqhZZs)
**CLICK TO ENLARGE**

> “When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more, nor less.” -- Humpty Dumpty

My first reflection puzzle: [The effect of living backwards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63209/the-effect-of-living-backwards)

Comment: Since the image is a perfect mirror, one can flip it in image editing software and calculate the differences. To make this more difficult, you could apply a [slight distortion filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqu8P.jpg) to the image :)

Comment: @R.M Certainly! But would that be *faster?*  The [last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63209/the-effect-of-living-backwards) got 4 answers in the span of 20 seconds, or so it was said.

Comment: Yes, of course. I found all the differences using photoshop in less than a minute, which is something I wouldn't be able to do manually. I didn't post because I thought that's cheating.

Comment: As with the first puzzle, please add the source/reference for the image to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image]
>  horse head
>  chimny on house
>  symbol on goat?'s hat
>  glasses on goat flipped
>  signature not flipped
>  egg missing
>  cup says jam
>  eyes in kite are shiny
>  shine on kite changes

Comment: ☑ for you, but no secret imaginary bonus points as you did not properly identify the "thing" on the sheep's hat. (Don't be discouraged, no one else seemed to recognize it either.)

Comment: @Chowzen it's the puzzling.stackexchange.com logo

Comment: Heh, I assumed it was part of the drawing :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll start with a few:

> The sheep's hat has a symbol on the right, but not the left.
>  The rocking horse in the top row of the window (left-hand side of the right image) is reflected wrong.
>  The house in the top row of the window (right-hand side of the right image) has a chimney in the right image, but not the left.

Also:

> There is one fewer can (?) on the table on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to puzzledPig's answer..

> The signature on the bottom left/right was not flipped.
>  The eyes on the crest/shield/whatever it is hanging on the table is slightly different
>  The sheep's glasses' lenses are not flipped